# List is returning null when mapping an array to POJO in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, nullpointerexception

I am facing a null pointer exception when mapping properties in application.properties to java pojo classes. Following is the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.monitoring.wemon.WemonProperties.getWebsites()" because "this.wemon" is null
    at com.monitoring.wemon.runnable.WemonRunnable.run(WemonRunnable.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:an]
```

Following is my application.properties file

```
#Task scheduler
periodic.check.time.ms = 5000

#Wemon
wemon.websites[0].url="https://www.google.com/"
wemon.websites[0].content="I'm Feeling Lucky"
wemon.websites[1].url="https://www.google.com/"
wemon.websites[1].content="I'm Feeling Lucky"

#logging
logging.file.path= /
logging.file.name = wemon.txt
logging.level.com.monitoring.wemon = INFO
```

Following is my class where I am using @ConfigurationProperties annotation. However, it shows me following suggestion

> When using @ConfigurationProperties it is recommended to add
> 'spring-boot-configuration-processor' to your classpath to generate
> configuration metadata

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("wemon")
public class WemonProperties {

    private List<Website> websites = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static class Website {

        private String url;
        private String content;
        
        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }
        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }
    }

    public List<Website> getWebsites() {
        return websites;
    }

    public void setWebsites(List<Website> websites) {
        this.websites = websites;
    }


}
```

Following is the class where I am autowiring the configuration properties file.

```
public class WemonRunnable implements Runnable {

    private WemonProperties wemon;
    
    @Autowired
    private void setWemon(WemonProperties wemon) {
        this.wemon = wemon;
    }
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WemonRunnable.class);
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("website list size : "+wemon.getWebsites().size());
        logger.info("scheduler running");
    }
}
```

Can anyone please point the mistake where I am going wrong which is why I am facing the null pointer exception?

Answer (score 0):

class `WemonRunnable` should use `@Component` then wemon will be injected

Comment: I use @component on WemonRunnable but still null pointer exception is appearing

Comment: maybe setter inject is not working.
you could try constructor inject or SpringContextUtil 
[link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beichenhpy/websocket-client/dev/websocket-client/src/main/java/cn/beichenhpy/websocketclient/utils/SpringContextUtils.java)